# функция возвращает указатель на первый символ ch в строке, что возвращать если символ не найден?

Tags: c++

Есть функция которая ищет символ в строке и возвращает указатель на символ. что делать если символ не найден?

```
/* возвращает указатель на первый символ ch в строке*/
template <class T = char> 
const T* custom_strchr(const T* str, T ch)  noexcept   /* 'requires' --> C++20 */
    requires(std::is_same_v<T, char> || std::is_same_v<T, wchar_t>)
{ 
    const T *p = str;
    while(*p && *p != ch)p++;    
    return p;
}
```

Также есть функция которая возвращает адрес подстроки, аналогичный вопрос?

```
/* возвращает указатель на начало подстроки */
template <class T = char> 
const T* custom_strstr(const T* str, const T* sub_s) 
    requires(std::is_same_v<T, char> || std::is_same_v<T, wchar_t>)
{
    bool key = false;
    const T* p = str;

    while(!key && *p)
    { size_t i = 0;
        while(*(sub_s + i) && (*(p + i) == *(sub_s + i)))i++;
        if (!*(sub_s + i))
            key = true;
        else
            p++;
    }

    return  p;
```

Comment: Возвращать `nullptr`.

Comment: NULL. Все хорошие программы, должны делать проверку на ошибки и возвращаемые результаты :)
Да, это нудно делать, но нужно ;) Притом иногда приходится не тупо exit(1) делать а как-то возвращаться в то место, до ошибки =) Но иногда от этого нет смысла продолжать, т.к. это критическая ошибка. Ну в общем всегда, от любого действия ждать подлянки ;)

Comment: @FrancNet подскажите а как переписать **custom_strchr** , для **custom_strstr** сделал так return `(key ? p : nullptr);`

Comment: Я Сишник ;) С++ не понимать ;) Видите @Harry написал nullptr а я NULL :)

Comment: [Аналогичные функции](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) возвращают:  `strchr()` - NULL; `strchrnul()` - указатель на нулевой символ в конце строки. Программисты используют ту, что лучше подходит в конкретной ситуации

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так для `custom_strchr` как я понял вроде правильно так:

```
/* возвращает указатель на первый символ ch в строке*/
template <class T = char> 
const T* custom_strchr(const T* str, T ch)  noexcept   /* 'requires' --> C++20 */
    requires(std::is_same_v<T, char> || std::is_same_v<T, wchar_t>)
{ 
    const T *p = str;
    while(*p && *p != ch)p++;    
    return (*p) ? p : nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Не пойму как переписать компактно функцию `custom_strstr` , что было компактно как с первой функцией.